# (Linking)Problem in Berkeley DB in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, database, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

i am traying to start using Berkeley DB, i downloaded the latest version of DB available here:   [Berkeley DB 5.1.25.msi Windows installer, with AES encryption](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen)

after the installation i started Visual studio 2010 and i did the followng:

> Project -> "project name" Properties
>   -> VC++ Diretories -> include Directories

i added the path

> C:\Program Files\Oracle\Berkeley DB
>   11gR2 5.1.25\include

and i wrote the following code:

```
#include<db_cxx.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    Db db(NULL, 0);               // Instantiate the Db object

    return 0;
}
```

but it shows the following errors:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: virtual
>   __thiscall Db::~Db(void)" (??1Db@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function
>   _main C:\Users\Ahmed\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ssss\ssss\test.obj
>
> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Db::Db(class DbEnv *,unsigned int)"
>   (??0Db@@QAE@PAVDbEnv@@I@Z) referenced
>   in function
>   _main C:\Users\Ahmed\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ssss\ssss\test.obj
>
> Error 3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved
>   externals C:\Users\Ahmed\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\ssss\Debug\ssss.exe 1

i tried to follow the documentation, i read this piece of inf but i do not know how i can apply it in Visual Studio 2010:

> When building your application during
>   development, you should normally use
>   compile options "Debug Multithreaded
>   DLL" and link against
>   build_windows\Debug\libdb51d.lib. You
>   can also build using a release version
>   of the Berkeley DB libraries and
>   tools, which will be placed in
>   build_windows\Win32\Release\libdb51.lib.
>   When linking against the release
>   build, you should compile your code
>   with the "Release Multithreaded DLL"
>   compile option. You will also need to
>   add the build_windows directory to the
>   list of include directories of your
>   application's project, or copy the
>   Berkeley DB include files to another
>   location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the .lib's included with Berkley DB. There is probably a C:\Program Files\Oracle\Berkeley DB 11gR2 5.1.25\lib folder. You will need to add this folder, or possibly an appropriate sub folder. For example, there might be a Windows folder with x86 and x64 sub folders. You will need to add the appropriate sub folder to your 'Library Directories', which is just below the Include Directories options.

You will then have to specify to the linker which .lib's to include. You should check the software's documentation to see which one is needed.

There are two ways to add library dependencies in VS2010. The first way is to add the following line of code in an appropriate place inside of your project (in your snippet, it would belong at the very top of your only source file).

```
#pragma comment(lib, "filename.lib")
```

Note that your file name needs to be wrapped in "s, and that the line should not be followed by a ;.

The other way is to add the name in the Project Property settings. If you go to Project Settings->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. You should see the default .libs that you need to build console applications such as kernel32.lib, user32.lib, etc. Simply add the file the same way you did the additional include folder.

Comment: I realized this recently. Thank you Riley Barnelt.